# Tomcat 6.0.16 Undeploy doesn't remove MySQL Jar

Tags: java, locking, tomcat6, mysql-5.1, undeploy

I have following configuration on my system.

```
JDK 1.6
Apache Tomcat 6.0.16
Windows 7
```

and i am using `mysql-connector-java-5.1.21` jar file.

I have also set following parameter in Tomcat context.xml file

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="true" antiJARLocking="true">

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

</Context>
```

Still when i undeploy my application it doesn't remove `mysql-connector-java-5.1.21` jar everything else is removed.

when i tried to remove manually i got following error message:

```
File is open in Apache Tomcat
```

Please help

Comment: you need to stop tomcat before removing. I think tomcat is still openning the connection to database through the driver, therefore, it wont let you to delete the file

Comment: yes if i stop the tomcat service i am able to remove that file

Comment: This problem is not about the jar file. Your appliction needs to handle transaction better so it wont keep the connection forever

Comment: In application we am using Spring and Hibernate, so DB connection is completely handled by these frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

`Tomcat 6` has some classpath locking problems while redeploying applications.

The solution that should always work is to stop the Tomcat and delete the application's directory with the jar in it.

Comment: That's hectic job !! Does replacing mysql jar of some older version will solve the problem?

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani No, I think the problem is with tomcat 6. Make sure that all connections to the DB have been closed correctly.

Comment: DB connections and its lifecycle is handled by frameworks (Spring & Hibernate).